# A second hard drive, not working

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a second hard drive in my machine. It has worked correctly for.... ages. For some reason I can not work out, it has "stopped working". 
When I use fdisk-l the second drive it simply is not seen. Disk Checker does not see it. I do not know what it used to be called other than "second drive".
I have opened my PC and physically remounted it but still I can not see it.

It used 100% for extra storage, not dual boot or anything complicated.

As an aside, since it "failed to work" boot up times seem to be longer but I do not know if this is perception or coincidence.

Any clues from anyone ?

Comment: If you see the device nowhere (BIOS, OS, gparted LIVE, ...), chances are that the disk just passed away. As a last restort, I'd suggest trying to access the device by using an external hard drive docking station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second hard-drive is maybe just broken... Have you tried to use it in another machine ? You may also try to install it as master HDD and launch a bootable CD/USB key in order to check if it can be detected. I would also to put it in a USB enclosure, as you may get more debug information if plugged on a running system than at boot time.

The longer boot time suggests that either your OS is looking for the second HDD or has trouble accessing it. BTW, do you hear any noise (movement of heads on a classical HDD) ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to avoid the idea the drive is just broken. There is no noise from it whirring round, and the longer boot times "feel" like the OS i s looking for something it is not finding.
I will try putting it in an external tray but I need to find one first.
Thanks for your comments Vincent and Eduardo.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is just broken. Old fashioned broken.
I've tried a number of software solutions, from TestDisk, GParted and ..... and none of them were able to see the disk. I've also taken it out of the machine and put it in a USB enclosure. At this point I could hear a faint ticking as it was trying to mount, which, as mentioned above, would explain the longer boot times.

So, it is just broken.
P.

Comment: I'm no expert on hard drives, but it could also be worth checking if it gets enough voltage. Also try cleaning the pins with alcohol and reconnect.

Comment: Hi @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I'm no hard drive expert either, but...... the HD enclosure I bought had a separate power supply, so I had to /assume/ there are no power issues. It basically sounds like the HD swing arm is getting across c. 80% and then 'clicking back', like a record player arm hitting something and not playing all of The Lamb Lies Down on Broadway but never re-starting properly.... C'est la vie.